# Replace custom strings in files under Linux

Tags: regex, linux

I posted this question here on purpose, although - for my case - it is laTex related. The problem itself is generic though.

I've got several `*.tex`-source files containing references to images, e.g. `image1.jpg` and `image2.png`. I want to search all source file for a specified set of extensions (in this case **jpg** and **png**) and replace them with their pdf counterparts. Consequently I want to end up with the references `image1.pdf` and `image2.pdf`. To complicate the problem, I've got a list of 20 files (image3.jpg, image 4.png etc.) that I don't want changed.

Is there a simple solution out there (sed-based or any tool suggestions?) which might help? I'm no regular expressions guru, though. ;)

Comment: So you want to replace the *references* in the the `*.tex` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the filenames on your blacklist into some "magic" strings so that they will not look like filenames and will not be matched by anything.

```
cat your.tex | \
sed 's/image3.jpg/MMMAAAGGGIIICCC1/g' | \
sed 's/image4.png/MMMAAAGGGIIICCC2/g' | \
# ... all others on your blacklist
# then do regexp replacements
sed 's/\(image[0-9]\+\)\.\(png\|jpg\)/\1.pdf/g' | \
# ... convert all "magics" back
sed 's/MMMAAAGGGIIICCC1/image3.jpg/g' | \
sed 's/MMMAAAGGGIIICCC2/image4.png/g' | \
# ... and many others
# then output
cat > output.tex
```

Answer (score 2):

A easier way is:

- **`image3.jpg, image4.png`** --> **`image3.JPG, image4.PNG`**
- **`*.jpg, *.png`** --> **`*.pdf`**
- **`image3.JPG, image4.PNG`** --> **`image3.jpg, image4.png`**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `find` to get the file list, filter it with `grep -v` to remove the files you don't want changed and then use `xargs` to run on those files `sed -r -i 's/image([12])\.(jpg|png)/image\1.pdf/g'`. Take care, `sed -i` performs replacements in place, so it's better to backup your files in case something goes wrong. You can also use `sed -ibak` to let `sed` make a backup with `bak` extension before it modifies a file.